# PHP search not working if there are more than 2 keywords being searched

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to build a search box which will search in 2 columns.

html

```
<div class="autocomplete-list1">
    <input type="text" class="searchpropertyinputs areaname-list-completed" name="buildingorlocation" id="buildingorlocation" placeholder="Building or Location" onkeyup="autofillbuildingorlocation()" maxlength="50" />
    <ul class="areaname-list searchpropertyinputs" id="property_buildingorlocation_list"></ul>
</div>
```

php

```
$property_buildingorlocation = ($_GET['buildingorlocation']);
$property_buildingorlocation = str_replace(',', ' ', $property_buildingorlocation);


$select = $con->prepare(

"SELECT 
    * 
from 
    tbl_property 
WHERE 
    property_buildingname LIKE '%$property_buildingorlocation%' 
    OR property_areaname LIKE '%$property_buildingorlocation%'");

$select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$select->execute();
```

If i enter up to two key words like madison garden, then the result comes but if i put three like madison garden road then there is no result... can anyone enlighten me please..

Comment: there is data with like "madisongardenroad"

Comment: no but there is data like 'madison' so it should show up when 'madison garden road' is searched (that is what i think)

Comment: not because, the pattern is broken, is searched when found until end, if ends string defer then not found nothing. Search how run LIKE

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<?php
$property_buildingorlocations = array_filter(explode(',', $_GET['buildingorlocation']));
$query = "SELECT * from tbl_property ";
$count = count($property_buildingorlocations);
if($count){
   $query .=" WHERE ";
}
$i = 0;
foreach ($property_buildingorlocations as $property_buildingorlocation){
   $query .= "property_buildingname LIKE '%".trim($property_buildingorlocation)."%'";
   if(++$i !== $count) {
      $query .=" OR ";
   }

}



$select = $con->prepare($query);

$select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$select->execute();
```

Comment: please also tell me why my code was not working and what was i wrongly thinking

Comment: your input search keys were comma `,` separated right?

Comment: sometimes, but not always - basically i am trying to build a search to be conducted on autocomplete form... there are three columns, buildingname, areaname, cityname,  - sometimes that match is buildingname+areaname+cityname, sometimes it is areaname+cityname, somtimes just cityname and sometimes free text which does not match

Comment: my code is for comma `,` separated search keywords like `madison,garden,road`